# Как добавить другую таблицу без общего индекса?

Tags: mysql

Как добавить другую таблицу без общего индекса? Без JOIN.
Например

```
SELECT * FROM ANSWERS Answers, COMMENTS Comments ORDER BY time
```

---

```
<?php
if($row['Answers']) {
    echo 'ID IS TABLE Answer '.$row['time'];
} else if($row['Comments']) {
    echo 'ID IS TABLE Comment '.$row['time'];
}
?>
```

---

```
ID IS TABLE Comment 12:00 AM (Комментировал)
ID IS TABLE Answer 12:15 AM (Ответил)
ID IS TABLE Answer 12:23 AM (Ответил)
ID IS TABLE Answer 12:45 AM (Ответил)
ID IS TABLE Comment 12:56 AM (Комментировал)
ID IS TABLE Answer 13:12 AM (Ответил)
```

Не могу сделать типа хроника пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Comment' action, user, time FROM comments
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Answer'        , user, time FROM answers
ORDER BY time
```

и

```
<?php
    echo 'ID IS TABLE '.$row['action'].' '.$row['time'];
?>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!